# How to execute php if condition once time only

Tags: php

How to execute php if condition once time only and didn't check it again, i put if condition in for loop and  i want to check it one time only:

```
<?php
for($x=0;$x<3;$x++){
if($x == $x){ 
echo "";
}
else{
echo "hidden";
}

}
```

I need to execute first if one time only in for loop

Comment: `if ($x == $x)`? What is this doing?

Comment: you probably need if($x==some number)...

Comment: $y=5 if ($y==5) i need this if condition execute once time and didn't repeated in for loop

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0):

*I need to execute first if one time only in for loop*. Well that's not how you do it, you need to compare with a variable and upon success just use `break` to come out of the loop. Something like:

```
<?php
$y = 0;
for($x=0; $x<3; $x++){
if($x === $y){ 
echo "X is Equal to Y";
break;
}
else {echo "hidden";}
}
echo "<br>". "You're outside the loop!";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag, if flag is true don't execute if condition.

```
<?php

$flag = 0;

for($x=0;$x<3;$x++) {

    if($x == $x && $flag == 0){
        echo "";
        $flag = 1;
    }
    else{
        echo "hidden";
    }

}
```